# /usr/bin/env : The term '/usr/bin/env' is not recognized as the name

Tags: python, django, terminal, environment-variables, python-venv

I have a problem with django in python, i just installed in couple of days and it gave an error when every time i run it

/usr/bin/env : The term '/usr/bin/env' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- /usr/bin/env python "d:\Documents\Python\ecommerce\manage.py"
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/usr/bin/env:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to the interpreter in the shebang line. For example, in your python, use: #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: i use window so what should i do? i am really confused right now

Answer (score 0):

I think you deleted your virtual environment

Try this in your project folder:

```
pipenv shell
pipenv install django
```